# Python: get path to file in sister directory?

Tags: python

I have a file structure like this:

```
data
   mydata.xls
scripts
   myscript.py
```

From within myscript.py, how can I get the filepath of mydata.xls?

I need to pass it to xlrd:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
```

and relative filepaths like '../data/mydata.xls' don't seem to work.

Comment: What error message do you get? Where do you start your script from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `os.path.abspath(<relpath>)` to get an absolute path from a relative one.

```
vinko@parrot:~/p/f$ more a.py
import os
print os.path.abspath('../g/a')

vinko@parrot:~/p/f$ python a.py
/home/vinko/p/g/a
```

The dir structure:

```
vinko@parrot:~/p$ tree
.
|-- f
|   `-- a.py
`-- g
    `-- a

2 directories, 2 files
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to made it independent from your current directory try

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../data/mydata.xls')
```

The special variable `__file__` contains a relative path to the script in which it's used. Keep in mind that `__file__` is undefined when using the REPL interpreter.

Comment: +1 For a solution that will work even when the script is invoked from some other directory.

Comment: Doesn't work: produces: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my/file/path/load/../data/mydata.xls'

Comment: @AP257: Is the path in the error message correct or not? You can translate it to an absolute path using `os.path.abspath`, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Without wraping that into `os.path.abspath` that will not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
directory = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
final = os.path.join(directory, 'data', 'mydata.xls')
```

or simply

```
os.path.abspath('../data/mydata.xls')
```

Answer (score -1):

From you comments, it seems that `book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)` doesn't like relative path. You can create a path relative to the current file `__file__` and then take the absolute path that will remove the relative portions (`..`)

```
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../data/mydata.xls')
book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

Comment: -1 It seems that you don't understand that a ".." relative path is relative to the *current working directory* whereas the OP wants a path that's relative to his *script directory*; it's nothing at all to do with `xlrd`. Secondly `__file__` is the path to the *currently executing file*, which is no use if the OP wants to put his code in an imported utility module.

Comment: @John I failed to see how my answer is any different from the previous answers except that I remove the path "relative" parts. I am simply mixing answers from Vinko and Adam. Is it my explanation that granted me a down vote? The OP does not talk about a relative directory but from his myscript.py file. I agree that using __file__ is of no use if it is intented to be used in a module but the OP did not specify this.

Comment: Other answers don't include your fatuous first sentence. xlrd.open_workbook() merely passes the filename unmodified to the built-in 'open()' -- "doesn't like relative path" is a nonsense.