# executing windows command line operation from python

Tags: python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python)

I want to execute a windows command line operation using python. To execute the command I have to go to a particular directory within my system and then execute the command.
for example

1) Go to a particular directory c:\some\directory

2) then use command somecommand -x -y

I saw some posts on this topic but I was not able to figure them out properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to change the working directory then execute a command. So:

```
os.chdir(DIRECTORY);
os.system(COMMAND);
```

- [os.chdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) - Set the current working directory.
- [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) - Execute a "system" command.

If setting the working directory is not required you could just specify the full path to *os.system*.

Also, you might want to check out [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) as it might be more what you're [looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762468/subprocesses-with-different-working-directories-problem-with-python).

Comment: thanks it worked but is there a different method to achieve it, because I have ssen few posts where it is recommended to use subprocess module instead of system

Comment: Correct. You'll likely want to use subprocess as I said. Perhaps this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762468/subprocesses-with-different-working-directories-problem-with-python