# How do I run "git update-index --no-skip-worktree src/Folder/MyFile.cs" from python script

Tags: python, git

I want to run `git update-index --no-skip-worktree C:\dev\src\Folder\MyFile.cs` from python script", but I encountered 2 problems:

1. My script doesn't run from the git folder, so I need to somehow make it understand this is a git repo. I saw `git -C` should help but wasn't able to make it work.
2. I tried using subprocess.run and subprocess.Popen, but I get return code 0 and the file is not ignored.

How can I run it from my script?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to ignore a tracked file, you'll probably want to read the [Git FAQ entry that says that what you're doing won't work](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).

Comment: I read it already, thank you. I am using it for a very special case and this is exactly what I need.
The only problem is I can't seem to make it happen from my python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is just that the command is not being run in the right folder, have you tried adding the `cwd` keyword argument to `subprocess.run`? So if your current call is

```
subprocess.run(['git', 'update-index', '--no-skip-worktree', 'C:\\dev\\src\\Folder\\MyFile.cs'])
```

then change it to

```
subprocess.run(['git', 'update-index', '--no-skip-worktree', 'C:\\dev\\src\\Folder\\MyFile.cs'], cwd='path\\to\\the\\relevant\\folder')
```

Also, make sure to escape any backslashed in file paths, as I did here - otherwise they won't be understood as normal backslashes by Python.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently my issue was the fact I used a relative path instead of an absolute one as in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762468/python-subprocess-with-different-working-directory)
Now I managed to get it to work both ways:

1. `subprocess.run(f"git -C {path_to_repo_folder} update-index --no-skip-worktree {path_to_file}")`.
2. `subprocess.run(['git', 'update-index', '--no-skip-worktree', '{path_to_file}'], cwd='{path_to_repo_folder}')`
   I ended up using (2) as it is more elegant. Thanks [David Husz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13946974/david-husz)!