# Get path to file within a package?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a Python package which is organized like this:

```
package
|- subpackage
|  |- code.py
|  |- window.ui
| ...
```

In `code.py` I want to access the file `window.ui` via

```
PyQt4.uic.loadUi('window.ui', self)
```

This works well, if I just run `code.py` with `subpackage` as the working directory. But if I import the package from another working directory, this file cannot be found:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'window.ui'
```

**My question:** How can I get the path name of the directory the file `code.py` is placed in, in order to create the absolute path name of `window.ui`. Or, how can I most efficiently access the file `window.ui`.

I tried `os.path.abspath('.')` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758866/python-get-path-to-file-in-sister-directory), but it only returns the absolute path of the current working directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use absolute path of the file instead of relative path.

```
abspath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "window.ui")

PyQt4.uic.loadUi(abspath, self)
```